# Debian apt-get failing with up-to-date dependencies

Tags: debian, apt-get, owncloud

I'm having difficulty updating `owncloud` from 9.0.1 to 9.0.4. I've set an apt exemption for owncloud because previous system-wide `apt-get upgrade` calls were ['upgrading' owncloud from 8.x to 4.x](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=30324).  But so far upgraded with `apt-get upgrade owncloud` has worked ok.  Now I'm hitting:

```
root@raspi:/home/pi# apt-get install owncloud
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 owncloud : Depends: php-doctrine-dbal (< 2.5) but 2.5.4-2 is to be installed
            Depends: php-pimple (< 2) but 3.0.2-2 is to be installed
            Recommends: exim4 but it is not going to be installed or
                        mail-transport-agent
            Recommends: php-aws-sdk (< 3) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: php-crypt-blowfish (>= 1.1.0~RC2-2~) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: php-dropbox but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: php-google-api-php-client (< 1) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: php5-imap but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: php5-ldap but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: smbclient but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However:

```
root@raspi:/home/pi# apt-get install php-doctrine-dbal php-pimple
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-doctrine-dbal is already the newest version (2.5.4-2).
php-pimple is already the newest version (3.0.2-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The `php-doctrine-dbal` and `php-pimple` are latest version, so why does apt-get think not?  I've tried running `apt-get install -f`, which reports `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`.  Does not fix the problem however. Assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with

```
aptitude install owncload
```

**aptitude** should see and install the dependencies automatically.

The problem here seems to be that the packages **php-dochtrine-dbal** and **php-pimple** are too new.